# Return Condition/Expression from a Case Statement

Tags: sql, case

I have searched all around and cannot seem to find a solution to this problem I'm having. I have a fairly large case statement (over 100 lines) that works and returns the result I am looking for. An example of the line is below:

```
case
     When (Description like '%job%'
     or description like '%job%fail%') then 'Job'
     Else 'Not Classified'
End as ATC
```

I have a case statement that returns the result 'Job' as expected. I would also like to create a separate case statement that returns the criteria that returns the condition that the record met, allowing me to evaluate which criteria are returning the match ( a 'job' vs. 'job failed' comparison). I'm aware that I can duplicate my case statement to output the criteria met, but I would like to repeat this analysis and am looking for a more easily replicable solution (something along the lines of reading the conditions from the above case statement). Any thoughts?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Side note: There are no `CASE` *statements* in SQL (not counting vendor specific procedural extensions). You mean a `CASE` **expression**.

Comment: Side note: Don't enclose identifiers, such as columns aliases in single quotes. Single quotes are for string (and date ...) literals. Use double quotes or vendor specific quoting if you have special characters in the identifiers.

Comment: Do you mean returning “job” as a result or using “%job%” as the condition?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to avoid repeating the logic you can wrap it up in a table expression.

```
with matches as (
    select *,
        case when Description like '%job%fail%' then 1 -- most specific first
             when Description like '%job%'      then 2 -- least specific last
             else 0
        end as MatchCode
    from ...
)
select *,
    case when MatchCode > 0 then 'Job' Else 'Not Classified' End as ATC
from matches
```